# laptop quite dead after update on 12.10 and calibre

Tags: 12.10, updates, restart

I have searched as thoroughly as I can so as not to waste anybody's time but I can't find any help.

I have a Toshiba satellite 300 with Vista Home Basic and running Ubuntu - dual boot.

Everything was running well.

This morning I updated the 12.10 and then saw calibre running and downloaded the latest version. In a terminal window loaded the commands as suggested by calibre for Linux and then opened the filw manager and double clicked on the claibre shell file to run it. Seemed OK.

Then clicked on calibre on the left hand bar and everything went black and dead.

I tried to start by pushing the start button - no light, no sound, nothing.

I removed the RAM and reinserted it, after removing power and battery for a while - nothing. It might as well be a paperweight.

Comment: It sounds like a hardware failure. Power supply or motherboard might be gone. Is there any fan running when you turn on? Any BIOS beeps? Does something show up on the screen?

Comment: There is absolute silence and darkness - totally NOTHING

Answer (score 2):

I concur; it sounds like a complete hardware failure of some type.  Check that the charger is actually on and working. The 300 lights the white AC power LED whenever a working power supply is plugged in. If the LED is not on, then there's no power getting to the machine.  Either the power supply is dead, or the power socket is damaged.  Also check the power board is working if you use one etc.  If you have a multi meter check the output of the power supply.

Remove all external devices: drives, monitors, docking station, monitors, mouse, keyboard...  *Everything*.  Check that the battery is inserted correctly, or remove it completely.   (A shorted battery can hold the power supply out completely, but that hardly every happens these days).

Hopefully it's just the power supply and the machine itself is OK.

Comment: I checked the power supply with a multimeter and that was it - thank you to both of you!