# Sony VGN-P530H dead after Ubuntu update

Tags: 18.04, updates, laptop, 32-bit

I've got a few old laptops and computers to format and get ready for donations to poor students so they may access online classes, and one of the most recent I got here was this Sony VGN-P530H.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS i386 on it and got everything up and running, then I left it updating and left to go home. Next day I'm here early and it's completely dead. Well, almost completely: it will turn on the power led, but that's the only sign it will give, everything else is completely dead. No booting, no beeps or anything. Keyboard won't work or anything.

I tried opening it to remove peripherals but it's internal design is very different so I kind of gave up on the idea as I didn't feel comfortable messing with it.

Any ideas on what could've happened? It was connected to power the entire time and battery is still charging (battery led will turn on as well if I leave for a while and then connect the charger).

Comment: Sounds similar to this question, something burned out/bloke.  Google that laptop and might find easy/cheap fix or not.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/214502/laptop-quite-dead-after-update-on-12-10-and-calibre?rq=1

Comment: Did you try putting the install USB (or whatever) back in and rebooting on that?